# Merge two images and retain its transparency

Tags: actionscript-3

It was a while since I programmed AS3. Now I have a problem where I need to merge the two images where the upper image is a png that must retain its transparency. The upper image is an area that must pass through the lower image. A bit like a masked layer.

The result of this merge should result in a a display object. This object will later be sent to a method with the following signature:

```
public function addImage (
    display_object:DisplayObject,
    x:Number = 0,
    y:Number = 0,
    width:Number = 0,
    height:Number = 0,
    image_format:String = "PNG",
    quality:Number = 100,
    alpha:Number = 1,
    resizeMode:String = "None",
    blendMode:String = "Normal",
    keep_transformation:Boolean = true,
    link:String = ''
):void
```

Any advice is of the utmost interest. Thanks!

UPDATE;

After some struggling I've come up with this:

```
var bitmapDataBuffer:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( front.loader.width, front.loader.height, true );     
bitmapDataBuffer.draw ( front.loader );

var bitmapOverlay:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( front.loader.width, front.loader.height, true );
bitmapOverlay.draw ( frontBanner.loader );

var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, front.loader.width, front.loader.height);
var pt:Point = new Point(0, 0);
var mult:uint = 0x00;
bitmapOverlay.merge(bitmapDataBuffer, rect, pt, mult, mult, mult, mult);

var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapOverlay);

pdf.addImage(bmp,0,0,0,0,ImageFormat.PNG,100,1,ResizeMode.FIT_TO_PAGE);
```

The problem is that my background image (represented by bitmapDataBuffer) will be totally overwritten by my upper image (the one I call overlay).

The overlay image is a png image. This image has a part of it that is transparent. Through this transparency I want to see my background image.

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your transformation, as an image of sources and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make overlay image over the buffer image in your case, you are to use `copyPixels()` with `mergeAlpha` set to true.

```
bitmapDataBuffer.copyPixels(bitmapOverlay, rect, new Point(), null, null, true);
```

This will place data from `bitmapOverlay` to those parts of `bitmapDataBuffer` where overlay's alpha is above 0, blending semitransparent regions with the background.

Answer (score 2):

You should be more specific about what kind of merge you want. You have a few options:

1. [BitmapData.copyPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()) - Provides a fast routine to perform pixel manipulation between images with no stretching, rotation, or color effects. This method copies a rectangular area of a source image to a rectangular area of the same size at the destination point of the destination BitmapData object.
2. [BitmapData.merge](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#merge()) - Performs per-channel blending from a source image to a destination image. For each channel and each pixel, a new value is computed based on the channel values of the source and destination pixels.
3. [BitmapData.draw](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) - Draws the source display object onto the bitmap image, using the Flash runtime vector renderer. You can specify matrix, colorTransform, blendMode, and a destination clipRect parameter to control how the rendering performs.

Each will work out for a different thing - the first will just copy some image over another (can keep/merge alphas). The second will merge channels data and modify them. The third one is the easiest and can draw one bitmap over another, as well as use blend modes.

Just chose one! :)

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what type of merge I want to do. I want to keep the transparency of the "upper" image (png) and not loose any quality on both images. 

Do you have any code examples?

Comment: Check out the links buddy, it's full of examples. Try something, write what are the results and what exactly do you want to achieve. You've got all the information, just use it, not look for someone to write your code!